# How to get the Parent hierarchy in the Tree View object

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, nested, treeview

Hi i have an tree object with parent and nested childrens to show the tree with checkbox. I need to get the parent and grand parent name till the hole hierarchy if the children is checked. My json below it has checked true property when its checked

```
    {
      [
        Name: All,
        checked: false,
        children: [
          {
            Name: 'software',
children: [
              {
                Name: 'children1',
                checked: true,
                children: [
                  {
                    Name: 'childen2',
                    checked: true
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
```

[image: Tree Structure]

In the Json Children2 is selected means i need in the format like 
All -> Software ->children1 ->children 2 like that...

Answer (score 0):

This fits to what you want:
[jquery-bonsai](http://simonwade.me/jquery-bonsai)